# How to create application with AppTheme and without action bar ?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to create application without action bar and with AppTheme, I mean for example progress bar should look like progress bar in android 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following changes in style.xml

styles.xml:

```
     <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
               <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
               <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
     </style>
```